# Allocate money from Donor to student

Tags: civicontribute

i doing customize CiviCRM 5.29.1 for Wordpress 5.5.1 last version.

i have create 2 contact type individual: Donor, Student

Donor donation money for student. Donation money allocate to student. student have money for study

Ex:

- Donor(Tomy) donation $500 for student(David) in 2019
- Donor(Tomy) donation $500 for student(David) in 2020
- Donor(Tomy) donation $500 for student(David) in 2020
- ....
- Donor(Nancy) donation $200 for student(Olive) in 2019
- Donor(Nancy) donation $400 for student(Olive) in 2020
  ...

I want when view student then see all history donation from Donor.
and when view Donor then see all history donation for student.

How can do that?
i try create new Contribution but i only see contribution from Donor but i not see Contribution allocate to Student.

please help me, sorry my english not good. hihi

i attached new Contribution
[image]

+++++++++
Soft Credit have maximum 10 row for each contribution. but Donor donation $10,000 for 100 students.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use soft credit section of the contribution form...

Create a contribution for donor but under soft credit section include student contact

Ref: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/soft-credits/

If you need more than 10 soft credit record for payment than implement preprocess hook via civicrm extension or wp plugin to add the number of count, something like

```
function modulename_civicrm_preProcess($formName, &$form) {
  if ($formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution') {
    $form->setVar('_softCreditItemCount', 100);
  }

}
```

or install the [extension](https://github.com/pradpnayak/contributionsoftcreditlimit) in civicrm and add below line in end of civicrm.settings.php file

```
$civicrm_setting['CiviCRM Preferences']['contributionsoftcredit_limit'] = 100;
```

Comment: Hi, i review Soft credit in new Contribution but i see maximum 10 row in each contribution. but my Donor donation for 100 students and more...can you help me more idea

Comment: can you split the amount in 10 payments?

Comment: Or via buildform hook try to support 100 rows

Comment: Hi, i can't split 10 payment, because my Donor bank transfer 1 time, difficult for accounting record. buildform hook?

Comment: Can i update go to menu Support -> Developer -> API Explorer v3 (or v4 but my screenshot is in v3)
choose entity ContributionSoft, Action create and set value for Contribution, Soft Credit Amount and Contact ID
Then use Execute button, i not see ContributionSoft in v4

Comment: uodated my answer

Comment: If you need more than 10 soft credit record for payment than implement preprocess hook via civicrm extension or wp plugin to add the number of count, something like

function modulename_civicrm_preProcess($formName, &$form) {
  if ($formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution') {
    $form->setVar('_softCreditItemCount', 100);
  }

}
sorry, can you help me explain, hehe.

Comment: Provided you extension, updated the answer